# How do I avoid Django's `|linebreaksbr` and Bootstrap style conflict?

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to store newline character inside model's `CharField` but it's not rendering correctly. `<br/>` and `<br>` both display as plain text, while `|linebreaksbr` is destroing bootstrap's styles in that text.

3 of my attempts to make it work:

```
<p>{{ greetings.title_2 }}</p>
<p><pre>{{ greetings.title_2 }}</pre></p>
<p>{{ greetings.title_2 | linebreaksbr  }}</p>
```

And the result looks like this:
[image]

I want both bootstrap's style (like in first line) and new line stored inside variable. There is a way to do that by deviding one model field in two and adding `<br/>` tag into html file, but I wonder if there is better and simpler way for that. Any ideas?

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. Using `linebreaksbr` on its own will not change the styling, although `linebreaks` (without the `br`) will wrap your content in `<p>` tags, which might. But if you want to store a `<br>` and have it actually render as a linebreak, use the `|safe` filter.

Comment: You're totally right. Actually both `|safe` and `|linebreaksbr` work now. Looks like it didn't work when I was putting `|linebreaks` before the line of code with `|linebreaksbr` and that wrapping with `<p></p>` influenced next line somehow. Thanks anyway. )